# Plone Multilang Sitemaps are Empty

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

Running Plone version 5.0.5 with plone.app.multilingual activated I have noticed the site maps behaving strangely.

If I go to mysite.com/en-gb/sitemap I get the sitemap view for that language, fine.

If I go then go to mysite.com/en-gb/sitemap.xml.gz, download and extract the file .xml file, I get an empty site map (please see contents of file, below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
</urlset>
```

I get the same site map if I go to mysite.com/sitemap.xml.gz.
Control Panel

I've tried checking over the "Languages" section but I can't see anything related to a site map there. I have of course ensured "Expose sitemap.xml.gz" is ticked in "Site".
Portal Catalog

I tried a clear and rebuild of the catalog to no avail.
collective.linguasitemap

Tried installing this but I don't think it works for Plone 5.0.5. When I try to install it on this Plone 5.0.5 site, buildout goes through okay but I get the following when trying to load my client:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/plone/z01/parts/client1/bin/interpreter", line 302, in <module>
exec(compile(__file__f.read(), __file__, "exec"))
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.24-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 76, in <module>
run()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.24-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 22, in run
starter.prepare()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.24-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 92, in prepare
self.startZope()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.24-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 268, in startZope
Zope2.startup()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.24-py2.7.egg/Zope2/__init__.py", line 47, in startup
_startup()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.24-py2.7.egg/Zope2/App/startup.py", line 118, in startup
load_zcml()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.24-py2.7.egg/Zope2/App/startup.py", line 52, in load_zcml
load_site()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.24-py2.7.egg/Zope2/App/zcml.py", line 46, in load_site
_context = xmlconfig.file(site_zcml)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 649, in file
include(context, name, package)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 548, in include
processxmlfile(f, context)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 380, in processxmlfile
parser.parse(src)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 110, in parse
xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
self.feed(buffer)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 213, in feed
self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 365, in end_element_ns
self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 359, in endElementNS
self.context.end()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 558, in end
self.stack.pop().finish()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 706, in finish
actions = self.handler(context, **args)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.24-py2.7.egg/OFS/metaconfigure.py", line 46, in loadProducts
xmlconfig.include(_context, zcml, package=product)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 548, in include
processxmlfile(f, context)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 380, in processxmlfile
parser.parse(src)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 110, in parse
xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
self.feed(buffer)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 213, in feed
self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 365, in end_element_ns
self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 359, in endElementNS
self.context.end()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 558, in end
self.stack.pop().finish()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 706, in finish
actions = self.handler(context, **args)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 548, in include
processxmlfile(f, context)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 380, in processxmlfile
parser.parse(src)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 110, in parse
xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
self.feed(buffer)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 213, in feed
self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 365, in end_element_ns
self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 359, in endElementNS
self.context.end()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 558, in end
self.stack.pop().finish()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 706, in finish
actions = self.handler(context, **args)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 548, in include
processxmlfile(f, context)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 380, in processxmlfile
parser.parse(src)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 110, in parse
xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
self.feed(buffer)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 213, in feed
self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 365, in end_element_ns
self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 359, in endElementNS
self.context.end()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 558, in end
self.stack.pop().finish()
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 705, in finish
args = toargs(context, *self.argdata)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 1397, in toargs
args[str(name)] = field.fromUnicode(s)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/fields.py", line 227, in fromUnicode
v = vt.fromUnicode(s)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/fields.py", line 137, in fromUnicode
value = self.context.resolve(name)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 179, in resolve
mod = __import__(mname, *_import_chickens)
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LinguaPlone-4.1.5-py2.7.egg/Products/LinguaPlone/browser/controlpanel.py", line 6, in <module>
from plone.app.controlpanel.language import LanguageControlPanel as BasePanel
File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.controlpanel-3.0.4-py2.7.egg/plone/app/controlpanel/language.py", line 3, in <module>
from Products.CMFPlone.interfaces import ILanguageSelectionSchema # noqa
zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/z01/parts/client1/etc/site.zcml", line 16.2-16.23
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.ATContentTypes-2.2.12-py2.7.egg/Products/ATContentTypes/configure.zcml", line 8.2-9.44
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LinguaPlone-4.1.5-py2.7.egg/Products/LinguaPlone/configure.zcml", line 9.2-9.31
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LinguaPlone-4.1.5-py2.7.egg/Products/LinguaPlone/browser/configure.zcml", line 12.2-12.70
ImportError: cannot import name ILanguageSelectionSchema
```

We have a few other Plone 5.0.5 sites that still create the sitemap.xml.gz file without any problems. It seems to only effect the site with multilang installed.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong or can anyone shed any light on this issue?

Thanks in advance!

### Edit #1

This is being discussed here:
https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/issues/91

Comment: Seems a bug... think about reporting it to https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues

Comment: Seems related to this: https://github.com/plone/documentation/issues/537#issuecomment-234931505

Comment: @marr You are correct, I will keep this updated as the discussion progresses for anyone interested

Comment: The issue is closed. Does your question still require an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that has since been resolved.